# Rearrange folder structure for data in sh_binary and sh_test?

Tags: bazel

Suppose I have source-files like this:

```bash
.
├── config.json
└── test.sh
```

I want to create an `sh_test` using these files.

However, when the test runs, `test.sh` expects `config.json` to be in a different place:

```bash
.
├── configs
│   └── prod.json    # config.json
└── test.sh
```

I do not want to rearrange my source-code to satisfy `test.sh` and I also don't want to add a bunch of file copying/moving to the start of `test.sh`.

Is it possible to tell Bazel how to arrange the files for `test.sh` in an arbitrary way?

Ideal syntax would be like this:

```py
sh_test(
  name = "test",
  srcs = [ "test.sh" ],
  data = {  
    "configs/prod.json": "config.json",
  },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `genrule`:

```py
genrule(
  name = "prod_json",
  srcs = ["config.json"],
  outs = ["configs/prod.json"],
  cmd = "cp $< $@",
)

sh_test(
    name = "test",
    srcs = ["test.sh"],
    data = ["configs/prod.json"],
)
```

Alternatively, you could write a macro that matches the syntax in your question:

```py
# BUILD
load(":sh_test.bzl", "sh_test")

sh_test(
    name = "test",
    srcs = ["test.sh"],
    data = {
      "configs/test.json": "config_test.json",
      "configs/staging.json": "config_staging.json",
      "configs/prod.json": "config.json",
    }
)
```

```py
# sh_test.bzl

def sh_test(name, data = {}, **kwargs):
    datas = []
    for dest, src in data.items():
        genrule_name = dest.replace("/", "_")
        native.genrule(
            name = genrule_name,
            srcs = [src],
            outs = [dest],
            cmd = "cp $< $@",
        )
        datas.append(genrule_name)

    native.sh_binary(
        name = name,
        data = datas,
        **kwargs
    )
```

Comment: I was afraid this would be the answer - feel like this should be a first-class feature in Bazel.

Comment: That could complicate the `data` attribute. Would it help to write a macro that expands a dictionary mapping into a series of genrules like the one above? I've edited the answer with an example.